# Could we use 'lawn-proud' in the same sense as 'house-proud'?

Tags: american-english, phrase-meaning

The meaning of the term *house-proud* apparently has shifted, at least in the US, from meaning

> very worried about your house being completely clean and tidy, and
> spending a lot of time making it so
> ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/houseproud))

...which is how I think of it, to simply meaning

> proud of one's house or housekeeping ([M/W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/house-proud))

Given that, would it be a stretch to use the term *lawn-proud* to describe someone who obsesses over the state of their yard/garden? If it would not be generally understood in that sense, is there a word or a succinct phrase that would fit ?

Comment: House proud, but not yard proud: https://goingforwardblog.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/yard-work/

Comment: “Yard-proud” appears to be used in the sense you suggest, though not a common expression. https://books.google.it/books?id=an6TnsAzW9wC&pg=PA60&dq=%22yard+proud%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHja6e-vjvAhUEPewKHUJaBYcQ6AEwAnoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%22yard%20proud%22&f=false - https://books.google.it/books?id=qu4ZvNzC0KMC&q=%22yard+proud%22&dq=%22yard+proud%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHja6e-vjvAhUEPewKHUJaBYcQ6AEwBXoECAYQAw - https://books.google.it/books?id=VBELAQAAMAAJ&q=%22yard+proud%22&dq=%22yard+proud%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif_IOk-_jvAhXCwAIHHbktAyQ4ChDoATAEegQIBxAD

Comment: You _could_ use it on the understanding that it was a coinage and not a recognised expression.

Comment: 'Someone who obsesses over the state of their yard/garden' sounds ideal.

Comment: @user66974 - That seems to support the idea that "proud of your house" is the common meaning, instead of the first usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Yes, and so concise. (-:

Comment: Apparently 'house-proud' now needs to be disambiguated. Conciseness is not always available.

Comment: @KateBunting - maybe the OP was in Wiltshire?

Comment: @KateBunting - coined, or borrowed from the lawn care industry?

Comment: I've been around since 1949 and for most of that time I've thought of a "house-proud" person as being someone who spends huge amounts of time and effort cleaning and tidying but not compulsively as in OCD. What I know as "house proud" from 1950s UK language sounds like what you say is the new US meaning.

Comment: It is my opinion and long experience that lawn-proud may be used in the suggested manner in the same way as car-proud is an extension of the construct ***-proud. But, being a matter of my opinion rather than authoritative reference, I regret that the question should be closed.